# ListView like WindowsLiveMessenger

Tags: wpf, listview

```
    <ListView Margin="0" Background="White" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Grid/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
                <Grid Width="Auto">
                    <Label Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="62,8,8,8" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30"/>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListViewItem>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

i'm new to blend !!
how to add items from code that contain those 2 controls

this question is similar to 
[How to write ListViewItem that contain image , text and button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907533/how-to-write-listviewitem-that-contain-image-text-and-button)

Comment: That is XAML, it doesn't evaluate to a boolean. What are you asking, anyway?

Comment: **@BoltClock : I'm asking to make a listview like windows live messenger with listview item included name and picture**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `DataTemplate` that should be applied to the items, but you do not bind the relevant properties at all.

i.e.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
    <Grid Width="Auto">
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="62,8,8,8" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

See those two bindings? Your data-objects need to provide those public properties, i named them `Name` and `ImageUrl` here.

```
// Data-object class example
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

If your data-object supports that you can just add items of that type to the ListView and it should display as you want it to.

This might not make much sense to you, if so, **make sure to read introductory material first**:

[Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
[Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)